# Can I add multiple elements in a single DD of Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working on php and now trying to learning Zend, I am trying to collect the age (Year/month) using zend_form. So I want to put 2 text boxes in the  same DD wrapper.

Can any one help me please.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could create a composite form element that comprises your two text fields. Then create custom decorator for that element to handle the aggregation. Then add the standard DtDd wrapper.

See this post by [MWOP](http://twitter.com/weierophinney) for an example: [Creating composite elements](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/217-Creating-composite-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't place many input boxes in single element's decorator (with some exceptions like radioboxes or multicheckboxes). Instead that, you must to remove decorator `Zend_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper` from both elements and place them in new `Zend_Form_DisplayGroup`. Then You can set `Zend_Form_Decorator_DtDdWrapper` to that DisplayGroup